# Webscraper doesnt scrape all the products details only 1 part

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I created a simple scraper for https://www.jdsports.com.sg/ , it scrapes the product sku,price and product page link. I used beautiful soup 4 and requests library.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.jdsports.com.sg/search/dunk/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
div = soup.find('div')

for price in soup.find_all('span', class_='pri'):
    print(price.text)

    pID = div.find('span', class_= 'itemOverlay')['data-productsku']
    print(pID)

    #product link
    pLinkback = div.find('a', class_='itemImage')['href']
    plink = f'https://www.jdsports.com.sg{pLinkback}'
    print(plink)

    print()
```

Th results:

```
SGD 69.00
16139956_jdsportssg
https://www.jdsports.com.sg/product/blue-nike-dunk-low-infant/16139956_jdsportssg/

SGD 99.00
16139956_jdsportssg
https://www.jdsports.com.sg/product/blue-nike-dunk-low-infant/16139956_jdsportssg/
```

The price is correct, however for the product sku and link it just repeats the 1st product. I've tried several different ways of finding elements by class etc but it doesnt seem to work. Im pretty new to this can anyone help? it would be greatly appreciated. I have attached the web page sceenshot below.
[product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M99c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get link, price and ID use following example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get("https://www.jdsports.com.sg/search/dunk/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

for item in soup.select(".itemContainer"):
    price = item.find("span", class_="pri").text
    pID = item.find("span", class_="itemOverlay")["data-productsku"]
    pLinkback = item.a["href"]
    plink = f"https://www.jdsports.com.sg{pLinkback}"

    print(pID, price, plink)
```

Prints:

```
16139956_jdsportssg SGD 69.00 https://www.jdsports.com.sg/product/blue-nike-dunk-low-infant/16139956_jdsportssg/
16140016_jdsportssg SGD 99.00 https://www.jdsports.com.sg/product/blue-nike-dunk-low-children/16140016_jdsportssg/
```

Comment: hi thanks for your solution, but I don't really understand why you used ` item in soup.select(".itemContainer"):` do you mind explaining will really help alot :)

Comment: @mattias `item in soup.select(".itemContainer"):` - we select all tags that contain `class="itemContainer"` (it's CSS selector). Then we iterate over all these tags.

Answer (score 0):

`pid` and `pLinkback` don't change because `div`, from which they are extracted, doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks I got that now